# Rescan to make & active: ERROR: Parameters must be numbered consecutively

Tags: latex3

If I do

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\zxNoExt}{O{}+m}{% Warning, expl syntax removes space.
  \tl_rescan:nn { \char_set_catcode_active:N \& } { \begin{tikzcd}[#1] #2 \end{tikzcd} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\zxNoExt[
/utils/exec={
  \def\foo#1{Hey #1 !}
},
]{
  \foo{green} & \foo{red}
  %%% I would like this to work as well:
  % & |[foo/.style={color=#1}, foo=red]| Hey
}

\end{document}
```

Then this will fail with an error `ERROR: Parameters must be numbered consecutively. ##` because of the `\def\foo#1`. My guess is that the rescan interpret in a weird way the `#` symbol, but I am not sure how to fix this issue in a clean way. Ideally, I'd prefer the solution to be LaTeX3 if possible.

**EDIT**

The current answer does not really solve my issue due to the use of global catcode redefinitions. I would really prefer a solution without global changes, as I am very worried about unexpected bugs. Here is for instance an example showing how such change can messup a setting with cleveref + split: if cleveref is loaded **before** the catcode redifinition it loads fine, but not if it is loaded after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}    
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
% Does not work if loaded here:
\let\fooamp&
\catcode`&\active
\let&\fooamp

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\zxNoExt}{O{}+m}{% Warning, expl syntax removes space.
  \begin{tikzcd}[#1] #2 \end{tikzcd} 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
% Does work if loaded here:
% \usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}

 \begin{equation}
     \begin{split}
       a=&1+1
     \end{split}
 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

So I really want to avoid even asking myself if it is safe to change such options globally.

Another example where global options can lead to issues is if another package actually undo my catcode change.

Comment: are you sure you want to rescan, can't you simply replace &  by an active &

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How would you do that in LaTeX3 in a clean way? I think I used this method because it was advised to me at some points (I would never come with this solution myself), but I am open to any other solution. I used a while ago some complicated tricks in latex2 but it was really ugly, so I would love to see a clean latex3 solution for this.

Comment: Well I'd be tempted to make `&` globally active and do nothing at all in the macro.

Comment: in that case can't you do `\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand~replacement=\&,#1] ` and document the user should use `\&` in the body of the command?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well this is a bit too late now, my library is published since 2 years now. And I also like the `&` syntax.

Comment: @tobiasBora Could you rephrase your title so that future users with the same problem will be able to find it?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ok, just did it.

Comment: @tobiasBora Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a slower routine with `\regex_replace_all:nnN` that changes every `&` token (any category code) into an active `&`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\zxNoExt}{O{}+m}
 {% Warning, expl syntax removes space.
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \begin{tikzcd}[#1] #2 \end{tikzcd} }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \& } { \cA\& } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\zxNoExt[
/utils/exec={
  \def\foo#1{Hey #1 !}
},
]{
  \foo{green} & \foo{red}
  & |[foo/.style={color=#1}, foo=red]| Hey
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think I would just make `&` globally active

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\let\fooamp&
\catcode`&\active
\let&\fooamp
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\zxNoExt}{O{}+m}{% Warning, expl syntax removes space.
  \begin{tikzcd}[#1] #2 \end{tikzcd} 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\zxNoExt[
/utils/exec={
  \def\foo#1{Hey #1 !}
},
]{
  \foo{green} & \foo{red}
  %%% I would like this to work as well:
   & |[foo/.style={color=#1}, foo=red]| Hey
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to make `&` globally active, I want my changes to be local to the macros. Quantikz did that global change, and it often break some codes in a really weird way, I often need to disable it, or load it last etc…

Comment: @tobiasBora are you sure? do you have any example where an active & let to a non active one does not work? What gobal change did you use before? it has to be `\let` `\def` would not work here.

Comment: Yes, I added in my question an example where setting ```\catcode`&\active``` breaks cleveref when used together with split. `quantikz` has exactly this issue as well, as it uses exactly this code.

Comment: @tobiasBora ah yes so if (as I was contemplating) `&` was always active, then your cleverref example would be fine as you wouldn't be able to load it before the change in catcode

Comment: I'm not sure to see what you mean exactly, but I guess we can agree now that globally changing catcodes can have unexpected behaviors that one might want to avoid? Can't we just do some sort of token list replacements to solve this issue without global changes, or alike?

Comment: scan tokens is so fragile I'd still do this rather than rescan, but other people are free to post alternative answers, you don't have to accept thi sone. @tobiasBora

Comment: Oh really? In my experience I had more issues with global catcodes than scan tokens ^^' I guess I will wait for another solution then yes. But thanks for your help!